# MySQL setting a variable from a query and using it inside another query

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, sql-insert

I cannot get the code below to work. I'm trying to set a variable from a query and use it twice in another. The query runs fine if I copy the first query into the location of the variables. Since the first query will always return the same result I would prefer to not run it twice.

```
        SET @sid = (SELECT status_id
                    FROM user_relationship_status
                    WHERE status = 'LIKE');

        INSERT INTO user_relationships (user_id, target_user_id, status_id)
        VALUES (
          17,
          22,
          @sid
        )
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          status_id = VALUES(@sid)
```

Also user_id and target_user_id are both primary keys.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: `SELECT @sid:=status_id FROM...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid syntax in `SQL Server`, provided `sub-query` return's only one row.

```
 SET @sid = (SELECT status_id
                    FROM user_relationship_status
                    WHERE status = 'LIKE');
```

In `Mysql` you need to do like this

```
SELECT @sid:= status_id 
  FROM user_relationship_status
 WHERE status = 'LIKE'
```

Insert query should be like

I cannot get the code below to work. I'm trying to set a variable from a query and use it twice in another. The query runs fine if I copy the first query into the location of the variables. Since the first query will always return the same result I would prefer to not run it twice.

```
    SET @sid = (SELECT status_id
                FROM user_relationship_status
                WHERE status = 'LIKE');

    INSERT INTO user_relationships (user_id, target_user_id, status_id)
    VALUES (
      17,
      22,
      @sid
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      status_id = @sid
```

Comment: I get:  INSERT INTO user_relationships (user_id, target_user_id, status_id) VALUES (   17,   18,   @sid ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE   status_id = VALUES(@sid) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@sid)' at line 8 0.000 sec

Comment: @ovg - Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use below script to set @sid

SELECT status_id INTO @sid  FROM user_relationship_status WHERE status = 'LIKE' limit 1;

Comment: This also works for variables but I'm still having trouble with the insert part..

Comment: For error code 1452: users table does not any entry for user_id 18.